# Evaluating expressions in thymeleaf fragment

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to evaluate an expression that comes from a thymeleaf fragment. But it seems everything is just converted to a string.

Here is what I have in my main template

```
[(~{text:default_voucher::voucher-code})]
```

And `voucher-code` fragment looks like

```
<th:block th:fragment="voucher-code">${Voucher_code}</th:block>
```

But the value of `Voucher_code` does get shown. Instead just the text `${Voucher_code}` gets shown.

In my main template if refer the variable there instead of using the fragment, the voucher code shows up.

```
[[${Voucher_code}]]
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

**Update** 
I got it working by changing the main template to include the fragment like

```
<th:block th:insert="~{text:default_voucher::voucher-code}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't display a value like this in Thymeleaf:

```
<th:block th:fragment="voucher-code">${Voucher_code}</th:block>
```

Thymeleaf evaluates expressions inside attributes of tags.

Therefore, it should be something like this:

```
<th:block th:fragment="voucher-code">
    <p th:text="${Voucher_code}"></p>
</th:block>
```